# What is the easiest way to simulate trampoline?

Tags: physics

I've been fiddling with physics for about three hours now, I'm trying to create a trampoline physics scenario, or a stretched cloth with a pinned diameter catching a falling object.

My falling objects react with cloth, but keep falling through. Is this only possible via manual animation?

Comment: In mean time I posted “trampoline, but trampoline result is quite different from object in a bag, so as Jachym wrote -better post an example (even real photo with desired result). Also if you are looking for still image result or animation.
For still image you can try this addon “Modeling Cloth” to get some natural result https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1247&v=jNXBYI-WPU4&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 3):

Speaking to trampoline effect (simple one) ...

- falling object with two keyframes (start / end Z position) with Dynamic Effect  **Elastic** (T) set in Graph Editor with first keyframe selected
- "trampoline" worked better for me with **Soft Body** sim (Mass zero, Goal > Strength 1)

[image]

To protect object from penetration try for object Collision > **Outer Thickness** increase value a bit or for "trampoline" increase Solver > Step Size.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use cloth sim with drivers attached to the vertex weight of the cloth's  vertex group. The object, upon contact with the trampoline, would lower the weight while going down.

Or

Use a soft body to make the trampoline a jelly-like object.