# How can I catch Rigid Bodies using a Cloth in Blender 2.83?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

#### The Problem

So far I have not been able to perform a **Rigid Body** simulation on one object and a **Cloth** simulation on the other *and* have them interact with each other simultaneously.

The effect I want to that of several objects falling into a net in a realistic way.

#### Successful Simulations:

- Drop a subdivided plane with Cloth enabled onto another mesh with collision enabled.
- Animate a Rigid Body with "Passive" and "Animated" enabled into a Cloth plane with the corners pinned.

[image]

#### Other Methods Tried:

- [What is the easiest way to simulate trampoline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160171/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-trampoline)
- [How to make cloth 'catch' a falling object, slowing its fall?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/how-to-make-cloth-catch-a-falling-object-slowing-its-fall/73812)
- [Creating a Soft Body Surface that Responds to Different Masses of a Rigid Body Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118858/creating-a-soft-body-surface-that-responds-to-different-masses-of-a-rigid-body-o)

#### Is it Possible?

I would've thought that this was quite a common use case, however, the fact that I have been unable thus far, to find an exact guide on how to approach this problem, I'm beginning to think that it may not be possible to simulate the two entities together.

[image]

Comment: It's not natively built into Blender.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am trying to put a torus on a "cloth" string and i cant get them to interact

Comment: Apparently no way: Physics cross-simulation interactions?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1030/111042